# Where do Fallout Shelter screenshots get saved on PC version?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In the game I took a few pictures but I can't find them anywhere

**I am playing on PC version**

Answer (score 1):

Mine are under "My Documents", i.e.:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Games\Fallout Shelter\Screenshots
```